# Event invites sent via javamail and ical4j show as plain text in outlook 365

Tags: java, outlook, office365, jakarta-mail, ical4j

I'm having an issue with calendar invites when sent via javax.mail to a Outlook 365 account. The email is sent, but the body of the email is just the invite in plain text. I'm not sure if this is an know issue with Outlook 365 or if I'm doing something wrong, but I've tried to explore both options and I'm coming up short. Hope someone here can point me in the right direction.
'''

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", ResourceBundle.getBundle("system").getString("email.host"));


Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
session.setDebug(true); // Verbose!

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
message.setSubject(frame.getEventTitle());

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipientAddress);


// Create an alternative Multipart
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");


// build and add the calendar
BodyPart calendarPart = buildCalendarPart(frame, recipientList, securityString);
calendarPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
calendarPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
multipart.addBodyPart(calendarPart);

// Put the multipart in message
message.setContent(multipart);

// send the message
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect();
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

and here is the buildCalendarPart function I call which constructs the iCal body

```
private BodyPart buildCalendarPart(DynamicFrame frame, List<String> recipientList, String securityString) throws Exception {

    BodyPart calendarPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    for(String recipient : recipientList) {
        sb.append(recipient + ";"); 
    }

    String status = "";

    // Create a TimeZone
    TimeZoneRegistry registry = TimeZoneRegistryFactory.getInstance().createRegistry();
    TimeZone timezone = registry.getTimeZone("America/Mexico_City");
    VTimeZone tz = timezone.getVTimeZone();

    Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    startDate.setTimeZone(timezone);
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, frame.getEventDate().getMonth());
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, frame.getEventDate().getDay());
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, frame.getEventDate().getYear());
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, frame.getEventDate().getHours());
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, frame.getEventDate().getMinutes());
    startDate.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, frame.getEventDate().getSeconds());

    Calendar endDate = new GregorianCalendar();
    endDate.setTimeZone(timezone);
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, frame.getEventDate().getMonth());
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, frame.getEventDate().getDay());
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, frame.getEventDate().getYear());
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, frame.getEventDate().getHours());
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, frame.getEventDate().getMinutes());
    endDate.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, frame.getEventDate().getSeconds());

    // Create the event
    String eventName = "Progress Meeting";
    DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
    DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate.getTime());
    VEvent meeting = new VEvent(start, end, eventName);

    // add timezone info..
    meeting.getProperties().add(tz.getTimeZoneId());

    // generate unique identifier..
    meeting.getProperties().add(new Uid(frame.getWebcastId()));

    String uri = "mailto:"+sb.toString();
    // add attendees..
    Attendee dev1 = new Attendee(URI.create(uri));
    dev1.getParameters().add(Role.REQ_PARTICIPANT);
    meeting.getProperties().add(dev1);
    meeting.getProperties().add(Priority.MEDIUM);
    meeting.getProperties().add(Clazz.PUBLIC);


    // Create a calendar
    net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar icsCalendar = new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar();
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(Method.REQUEST);
    icsCalendar.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);


    // Add the event
    icsCalendar.getComponents().add(meeting);


    // Fill the message
    calendarPart.setContent(icsCalendar.toString(), "text/calendar");// very important


    return calendarPart;
}
```

[image: screenshot of message received in Outlook 365]
screenshot of message received in Outlook 365

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT use the addHeaderLine method.  Those strings you're adding are not header lines.  You need to set those as parameters on the Content-Type of the appointment body part.